# How to convert JSON data to XML?

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I'm currently converting json received from an external API to XML, and the XML is returned by my API:

```
     var result = util.getAdis(firstName, lastName, dob, function(err,response,data){
        if(!err) {
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            var root = builder.create('ADIS')
            data.forEach(person => {
                var item = root.ele('person');
                item.att('GivenName', person.GivenName);
                item.att('MiddleInitial', person.MiddleInitial);
                item.att('Surname', person.Surname);
                item.att('Event', person.Event);
                item.att('EventDate', person.EventDate);
            })
            var xml = root.end({ pretty: true });
            res.type('application/xml');
            res.send(xml);   
        } else {
            console.log(err)
            res.send(500)
        }
    });
```

I'm using [an XML builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlbuilder) this works great. But is there a better way to write this code? SO it is dynamic, I don't want to assign each elements manually.

The JSON looks like this:

```
[{
    GivenName: 'Mable',
    MiddleInitial: 'G',
    Surname: 'Stewart',
    Event: 'A',
    EventDate: '2014-07-16',
}]
```

Comment: You can loop through an object's properties with `Object.entries()`.

Comment: You can try jsontoxml https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsontoxml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the usage of the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlbuilder#usage) , the first example, they show we the way to use `.ele` function.

```
.ele('node_name', {node_attr_object: attr_value} , 'node_value')
```

In your case, you need to create a node called `person` with all attributes are the properties of the `data` item, then in the loop, you only put the object as the second parameter of `ele` function instead of set each attribute by manually.

```js
var result = util.getAdis(firstName, lastName, dob, function (err, response, data) {
  if (!err) {
    var data = JSON.parse(data);
    var root = builder.create('ADIS')
    data.forEach(person => {
      root.ele('person', person);
    })
    var xml = root.end({ pretty: true });
    res.type('application/xml');
    res.send(xml);
  } else {
    console.log(err)
    res.send(500)
  }
});
```

with data is

```
[{
    GivenName: 'Mable',
    MiddleInitial: 'G',
    Surname: 'Stewart',
    Event: 'A',
    EventDate: '2014-07-16',
}]
```

you will get back an xml string like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ADIS>
  <person GivenName="Mable" MiddleInitial="G" Surname="Stewart" Event="A" EventDate="2014-07-16"/>
</ADIS>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a great npm module with 8M downloads/week.

They wrote on their wiki the way to [convert Array/Object](https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/wiki/Conversion-From-Object)

This is an example of `Conversion from Array`.
You can try it at [RunKit](https://runkit.com/dragonnpoulp/5df7002d21d6b8001be36de2)

```js
var builder = require("xmlbuilder")

var data = [{
    GivenName: 'Mable',
    MiddleInitial: 'G',
    Surname: 'Stewart',
    Event: 'A',
    EventDate: '2014-07-16',
}]

var xml = builder.create('ADIS')
  .ele({ person: data })
  .end({ pretty: true})

console.log(xml)
// <?xml version="1.0"?>
// <ADIS>
//   <person>
//     <GivenNam…  <EventDate>2014-07-16</EventDate>
//   </person>
// </ADIS>
```